# How to match and extract part of result in regular expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript I have this code that gets an array of all matches

```
    var m = body.match(/'(http[^,]+\/p\/[^,]+\d+)'/g);
    res.write(m.join());
```

The problem is I need the quotes wrapped on it, to get the results I want, but when I actually get the result, I don't want the quotes included in each string in the array.

How can I remove that?

Thanks

Comment: how your input looks like?

Comment: Its a full string of a html page.

Comment: Why not simply `body.match(/'(http[^,]+\/p\/[^,]+\d+)'/g).map(function(s){ return s.slice(1,-1) })` ?

Comment: @dystroy, i want everything in regex pls.

Comment: Then you'll probably have to use a loop and `exec`...

Comment: I think it can be done with this http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html, but im not sure how.

Comment: There's no negative lookbehind in js

Comment: @omega it can't be done with regex alone in js, since it won't support lookbehinds.

Comment: @dystroy your suggestion is simple and nice.

Comment: I don't get why there's a deleted question which got a downvote followed, long after, by an identical answer which was upvoted...

Comment: @dystroy The other answer appeared while I was writing mine, and I didn't see that until I answered. But I didn't remove mine because it had more explanations. Not sure why the other answer was downvoted, tough. It wasn't a strategy of mine to place my later answer at the top, even if it can seem so.

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses create a numbered capturing group, which allows you to access that part of the match.

When you use `String.prototype.match`, you get an array where the first element is the match, the second one is the first capturing group, and so on:

```
"a1a".match(/a(\d)a/); // [ "a1a", "1" ]
```

However, that only happens when the regex doesn't have the global `g` flag. Otherwise, you get an array with all matches:

```
"a1a-a2a".match(/a(\d)a/g); // [ "a1a", "a2a" ]
```

It is still possible to access the capturing groups with a global flag, but not with `match`:

```
var regex = /a(\d)a/g,
    str = "a1a-a2a",
    match;
while(match = regex.exec(str)) {
    match[1]; // First capturing group of each match
}
```